# VS2012 can't connect to WP8 emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I use

- Windows 8 Pro 64 bit
- AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core (support Hyper-V)
- Visual Studio 2012 update 2
- Latest Windows Phone 8 SDK
- Latest DirectX

My problem: Visual Studio can't connect to emulator. Exactly CAN'T CONNECT, because I can see running emulator from Hyper-V Manager when try to run project.

On picture I present situation:

[image]

I have following scenario:

1. Click "Run" on emulator
2. Hyper-V Manager I can connect to emulator and check that it's works, but in VS I see only "The Windows Phone OS is starting..."
3. After 5 minutes emulator turned off by himself.

I already check all popular similar discussion about that problem, but can't make it works.

Note: All works great a week ago.

Comment: Do you have a lot of free space on the drive that you have your operating system installed on? I noticed that the emulator wouldn't boot once I got below like 2gb of memory left on my HDD. It was SUPER annoying.

Comment: Yes, I have 100Gb+ free space on the system drive.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your emulator? Its pretty buggy. I get issues all the time with that thing.

Comment: Yes, I already reinstal emulators.

Comment: Hi, do you have a VirtualBox or other Virtual Machine? 
I know, I've a similar problem when I using VirtualBox and vmWare.. when I uninstall all VM on my computer, the connection between my Windows Phone emulator and my network work...

Comment: No, I haven't any other virtual machines.

Comment: When the emulator closed itself automatically, did you see any error reported in the visual studio. If yes what is the error.

Comment: No specific error - just standard "Deploying error", like in situation when trying to build to device, which doesn't connected

Comment: Try removing the image (and switches) in Hyper-V and then starting the emulator from VS

Comment: After looking at all the answers/comments here, I need to ask you if the project you are trying to run is fine and if possible can you share it with us, so that we can try out and eliminate that the project has no problems.

Comment: @Manvik - this not project fail. I tried empty test project too.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the exact same symptoms.  For me, the following worked:

1. Shut down the emulator
2. From Hyper-V Manager, open Virtual Switch Manager
3. Select the Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch
4. Click Remove
5. Click OK

Once I did that, debugging from VS magically worked again.  Checking back in Virtual Switch Manager shows it automatically recreated the switch for the emulator.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

See this might be A suggestion as well it can be a solution for you application

Try Re Installing win phone 8 sdk. 
Also try running in different modes.

Thanks.

Comment: Re Installing win phone 8 sdk - this is first what I did!

Comment: Ohh sorry i thought to start from the basic :) Ill look into it Further. i myself have a Hyper V issue and struggling.

Comment: Try Un-Installing and Re-Installing Hyper V and create a new Virtual Switch. Since error is not reproduced here. It is very difficult to know the reason of the problem.

Comment: Go through this link and check weather the emulator is opening without visual studio or not. Might give you a break. gauravmahajan.net/2013/02/06/launch-windows-phone-8-emulator-without-launching-visual-studio-2012/